# switch to terminal opened from autocomand

Tags: neovim, autocmd, lua, init.lua

I am trying to create autocommand to run current python file in a terminal, when it is saved. It is working with the following autocommand:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWritePost", {
  group = augroup("PythonAutorun", {clear = true}),
  desc = "Start autorunning python file on save",
  pattern = {"*.py"},
  callback = function (ev)
    vim.cmd(':split | terminal python %')
    print(vim.inspect(ev))
  end
  }
)
```

The problem is, contrary to just running `:term` directly, focus stays in python file window. Therefore, I need to manually switch to terminal window and enter terminal mode and quit.

What I want to achieve, is that when autocommand is triggered - focus switches to the newly created terminal window and terminal mode is activated.

I tried to use `TermOpen` event, but none of the `Term*` events trigger, if it is spawned like shown above.

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("TermOpen", {
  group = augroup("FocusTerm", {clear = true}),
  desc = "When terminal is run, shift focus to it",
  callback = function (ev)
    print(vim.inspect(ev))
  end
})
```

What would be the shortest way to achieve the functionality?